# jQuery MouseLeave across a group of classes?

Tags: jquery, mouseleave

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="outer-field"></div>
<div class="outer-field"></div>
<div class="outer-field"></div>
<div class="outer-field"></div>
```

Which is used within the function

```
jQuery('.outer-field').live('mouseleave', 
      function () {
        console.log('in outer');
});
```

My problem is that I only want the "mouseleave" function to fire when it is outside *ALL* of these ? At the moment it fires moving from one to next `.outer-field` ?

i.e. I want it to fire once if it is outside

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to encapsule all divs in one your listening for mouse leave...

Comment: unfortunately that option isn't available as the div's are added to the `document` ?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't do that... ?

Comment: @Christopher - jQuery plugin adds a bunch of div's to the outer document. It doesn't surround the `div` with any outer `#id` or `.group-class` - so I'm wondering how I can instead group `.outer-field` to incorporate something like `:any` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the HTML structure (which would be a simpler solution), you need to delay the execution of the mouseout code by wrapping I'm a function passed to setTimeout. Store the returned I'd in a variable and use clearTimeout on mouseover of one of the elements, which will cancel the scheduled execution.

Comment: I was thinking something along these lines:

`var toutId = null;

jQuery('.outer-field')
    .live('mouseover', function () {
        if(toutId != null) {
            clearTimeout(toutId);
            toutId = null;
        }
    }).live('mouseleave', function() {
        toutId = setTimeout(function() {
            //Do stuff here...
            alert('leaving');
        }, 500);
    });`

Comment: Sorry about the formatting - new to SO. I've set up an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Tryster/a8aEV/